# How to deploy Spring boot and React application together on GCP App Engine?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, google-app-engine, web-deployment

I don't have any experience in deployment and trying to deploy Frontend and backend together. I am able to successfully deploy the spring boot application.
I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.mukundmadhav.com/build-and-deploy-react-app-with-spring-boot-and-mysql-6f888eb0c600) and successfully generated a build.
Is it possible to deploy the frontend and backend together?
[image: This is how my folder structure inside target/classes/public look like]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this GCP [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/an-overview-of-app-engine):

> Use services in App Engine to factor your large apps into logical
> components that can securely share App Engine features and communicate
> with one another. Generally, your App Engine services behave like
> microservices.

Deploying two apps written in different language on a same runtime in App Engine standard is not possible as you won't be able to run Javascript apps if the current runtime in your `app.yaml` is Java.

My suggestion would be to split your applications into *separate services* as mentioned in the docs.

Finally, if you insist on a monolithic approach, consider deploying your app to a custom runtime in App Engine flex. Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build). Do note that it requires a `Dockerfile` so you will have to manage the containerization of your apps.

Comment: Thank you! I will checkout App Engine Flex

Answer (score 1):

We can deploy a spring boot backend application with react front end as a single JAR in GCP. I simply followed instructions in [tutorial](https://justincalleja.com/blog/posts/2016/serving-a-webpack-bundle-in-spring-boot/) , Created an app engine in GCP and ran this command - `gcloud app deploy ***.jar`

You need to create the jar using maven and then run the command on that jar. It will deploy in gcp.

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```